# Sortby parameter to sort users

Tags: sort, parameter

So for my post list, currently these are sortby `post_count`.

Now, I am trying to sort the posts by "most newest" or "recent"

Here is how the shortcode works

```
[sortby=post_count]
```

Other parameters can be found from [Order & Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters), however I could not find parameter for "most newest."

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `date` as a value to `orderby` and `DESC` as value to `order`. This will get posts which was published the most recently.

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It looks like [orderby] is not supported with the shortcode. I will probably work on it next weekend. =) Thanks Pieter

Comment: In your shortcode you should probably try `[sortby=date]` :-)

Comment: haha yeah, :P I tried that but no luck. It is not a big deal at this point. I set the sortby with user registered day. If I find out how to make it work, I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: If you don't succeed, post your shortcode. I suspect that something is wrong then in your shortcode. Always good to have a look at the source :-). Good luck

Comment: Sounds good! =) will do! :)